# What happens if I change an iOS App ID?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-id, bundle-identifier

I'm wondering, what would happen if I change my App ID to another bundle ID. Here is a short example:

Change from:
com.company.myapp.company-intentextension

To:
com.company.myapp.intentextension

Do I have to worry about my app in the app store in case I change this App ID?

Comment: It will be treated as another app, bundle id's are unique for each app

Comment: @MidhunMP And if I change it back to the previous ID, will it be accepted again?

Comment: As said, you will have two copies of same app with different bundle id and app name (If I'm remembering correct, app name is also unique)

Comment: @MidhunMP Thanks. This answers my question.